# Freeing up memory allocated for an arbitrary position at an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing code to manage insertions and deletions into array elements. I know that a linked list or some other data structure is better suited for this, but I'm limited to using an array.

Extra memory for the array allocations are managed by use of the `realloc()` function. However, for deletions, I must free up the memory allocated to the last element. For this, I tried using `free (a + n)`, `n` representing the last element, however, this ends up giving crashes like:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 
0x000000000158f018 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I believe that the crashes are expected, since the OS manages a list of allocations for the heap, and while `a` itself has been allocated through `malloc()`, the OS does not know about any allocations for `a + n`, resulting in a hard error.

How should I go around freeing up the last element stored in the array?

Comment: You can't free individual array elements. You can only free the entire block of memory that was returned by `malloc`.

Comment: You can use `realloc` to shrink the allocation just like you use it to add to the allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `realloc` to shrink the allocation:

```
array_size--;
array = realloc(array, array_size);
```

Comment: With this is there a possibility that underlying heap allocation actually won't be resized ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The memory manager might operate at various granularity levels. If the allocation doesn't shrink below the next threshold, there's no need to resize it.

Comment: If you need detailed control over memory allocation, you shouldn't use `malloc`, you need to write your own memory manager.